# How to declare Common method for multiple directive in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have three lines of similar code in multiple directive, which is actually doing some bind an event handler to the "focus".

```
var ele = $(event.target);
$($(event.target)).attr('tabindex', -1);
$(ele).trigger('focus');
```

this is creating code duplication issue, creating a service or factory method is not right way, as because i am dealing with DOM manipulation.

is there any way where i can make common method and pass my target and run above code to avoid code duplication.

Comment: are you looking for `require` option in DDO?

Comment: You could create a new directive just for the `focus` binding

Comment: @Jai, yes something like that.

Comment: FYI, your 3 lines of "code" could be minimized to just one: `$(event.target).attr('tabindex', -1);`.

Comment: @Michael: Creating directive and Injecting it on all directive ?

Answer (score 1):

Normally having code-repetition in some components, like Controllers/Linking functions, isn't a bad Idea because this helps you to make every component indipendent... This is necessary when you work with DOM parts, otherwise you'll get untestable code!

If you need to share Behaviour... Angular has a Directive Concept, so, you can do what you need as angular suggests:

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .directive('scaleTabindex', function() {
    
    return function ScaleTabindexPostLink(iScope, iElement, iAttributes) {
    
      function scaleTabindex(event) {
        var index = Number(iElement.attr('tabindex'));
        
        return iElement.attr('tabindex', index - 1);
      }
      
      iElement.bind('focus', scaleTabindex);
    };
  })
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<article ng-app="test">
  <button tabindex="100" scale-tabindex>Button 1</button>
  <button tabindex="100" scale-tabindex>Button 2</button>
  <button tabindex="100" scale-tabindex>Button 3</button>
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you I agree with your point making it component indipendent, but it is repeated many times, need to make one time.

Comment: this isn't a repetition, 
you need to apply the directive where you need to scale the tabindex but the BusinessLogic code is written only once...

Directives are multi-instance components!